# How to make a list saved as an attribute within a class iterable?

Tags: python, class, oop

I apologise if I've not framed the question well, but let me try and explain. I've written this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        

class Course:
    def __init__(self, name, capacity = 3):
        self.name = name
        self.students = []
        self.capacity = capacity

    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.capacity:
            self.students.append(student)
        else:
            return False

    def display_students(self):
        print(list(self.students))
```

Post that, I'll create some student objects and keep adding them to the courses. For each course, the students keep getting added to the variable self.students inside the class for Courses. Now, if I want to iterate through this list and print the name of the students, I get something like this: '[<**main**.Student object at 0x7fc46dade5b0>, <**main**.Student object at 0x7fc46dade760>]'

How do I make it so that I get back the names of the students instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, never mind. I figured it. The method should read:

```
def display_students(self):
        for item in self.students:
            print(item.name)
```

Leaving this here in case it helps someone else. So 'item' here is actually a 'Student' object.

Answer (score 1):

An even better way would be to change the string representation of your Student objects to something more user friendly:

```py
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name  # assuming name is a string
```

This way you don't need to change anything in your Course class.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the student instance not the student's attributes.

If you want to print just the name:

```
def display_students(self):
        for student in self.students:
            print(student.name)
```

If you want to print the name and maybe other attributes:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, hobby):
        self.name = name
        self.hobby= hobby
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Name: " + self.name + ", Hobby: " + self.hobby)
```

Now you can print an instance and instead of the memory address of the instance, it will print whatever the **str** method returns.

```
student1 = Student("John", "Tennis")

print(student1)
```

This will print out

```
Name: John, Hobby: Tennis
```